# Streaming a ResultSet as RDF using a custom vocabulary

Tags: java, stream, rdf, resultset, jena

I need to stream a Jena `com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet` obtained from a query to a remote endpoint converted into an RDF output format.
I know Jena provides a `ResultSetFormatter.toModel` facility for that, however I have the following constraints:

- I want to use a different representation/vocabulary and not the one provided by Jena, and
- I don't want to load the data in memory. In other words I don't want to create a `Model` and fill it with the `ResultSet`, but streaming out the triples while I iterate on it, to control memory consumption.
- I still want to benefit by the Jena serializers

I have seen the `StreamRDF` interface, but I am not very clear about how to use it effectively.
What could be a correct approach in this scenario?

Comment: Asked and answered on the Jena users list.

Comment: I integrate an alternative and more compact way of doing it, using Jena utilities, as suggested in the conversation in the users list.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented works for me, so I post it as answer.
The snippet below should be informative enough, as it covers the requirements in the question. Notably, I created two classes, a `ResultSetTripleIterator` and a `QuerySolutionToTripleAdapter` interface. The first is responsible of streaming triples to the writer, while the second is meant to build an iterator of triples from each `QuerySolution`.

```
public class ResultSetTripleIterator implements Iterator<Triple> {
   private ResultSet rs;
   private QuerySolutionToTripleAdapter ad;
   private Iterator<Triple> it = null;
   public ResultSetTripleIterator(ResultSet resultSet, QuerySolutionToTripleAdapter adapter) {
      this.rs = resultSet;
      this.ad = adapter;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
      if(it != null && it.hasNext()){
         return true;
      }
      it = null;
      return rs.hasNext();
   }
   @Override
   public Triple next() {
       if(it == null){
           it = ad.adapt(rs.next());
       }
       return it.next();
   }
}
public interface QuerySolutionToTripleAdapter {
    public Iterator<Triple> adapt(QuerySolution qs);
}
```

And here is the application as example:

```
// Can be any OutputStream
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamRDF stream = StreamRDFWriter.getWriterStream(os, Lang.TRIG);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
        "http://data.open.ac.uk/sparql", "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> SELECT ?A ?B ?C WHERE {?A a ?B . ?A rdf:type ?C} LIMIT 100");

Iterator<Triple> iter = new ResultSetTripleIterator(qe.execSelect(), new QuerySolutionToTripleAdapter() {
    Integer rowIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Triple> adapt(QuerySolution qs) {
        rowIndex++;
        String ns = "http://www.example.org/test/row#";
        String pns = "http://www.example.org/test/col#";
        Resource subject = ResourceFactory.createResource(ns + Integer.toString(rowIndex));
        Property property;
        List<Triple> list = new ArrayList<Triple>();
        Iterator<String> cn = qs.varNames();
        while (cn.hasNext()) {
            String c = cn.next();
            property = ResourceFactory.createProperty(pns + c);
            list.add(new Triple(subject.asNode(), property.asNode(), qs.get(c).asNode()));
        }
        return list.iterator();
    }
});
stream.start();
StreamOps.sendTriplesToStream(iter, stream);
stream.finish();
```

However, Jena does not seem not support some RDF serializations for streaming, namely XML and JSON formats, resulting in a `org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: No serialization for language Lang:rdf/null`, for example.

**EDIT**

Thanks to feedback in the Jena users mailing list, the code above can be compacted by using Jena's utility classes to manipulate iterators and performing transformation.

The snippet can be rewritten as follows:

```
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamRDF stream = StreamRDFWriter.getWriterStream(os, Lang.RDFTHRIFT);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
        "http://data.open.ac.uk/sparql", "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> SELECT ?A ?B ?C WHERE {?A a ?B . ?A rdf:type ?C} LIMIT 100");

Transform<QuerySolution, Iterator<Triple>> m = new Transform<QuerySolution, Iterator<Triple>>() {
    Integer rowIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Triple> convert(QuerySolution qs) {
        rowIndex++;
        String ns = "http://www.example.org/test/row#";
        String pns = "http://www.example.org/test/col#";
        Resource subject = ResourceFactory.createResource(ns + Integer.toString(rowIndex));
        Property property;
        List<Triple> list = new ArrayList<Triple>();
        Iterator<String> cn = qs.varNames();
        while (cn.hasNext()) {
            String c = cn.next();
            property = ResourceFactory.createProperty(pns + c);
            list.add(new Triple(subject.asNode(), property.asNode(), qs.get(c).asNode()));
        }
        return list.iterator();
    }
};
Iterator<Triple> iter = WrappedIterator.createIteratorIterator( Iter.map( qe.execSelect(), m ));
stream.start();
StreamOps.sendTriplesToStream(iter, stream);
stream.finish();
```

Comment: Not all serializations can be written streaming.  JSON-LD and RDF-XML can't be. (A form of RDF/XML could be done but it will be verbose with namespaces declarations on each triple.).  Just for completeness, language RDF/NULL is now implemented.

Comment: This is partially true, it is possible to write JSON-LD ad RDF/XML streaming, the problem is that you need to still put something in memory (for example to stamp the context in json-ld at the end) or that the result might be excessively verbose (the case you mention). But changing serialization method because of the syntax might not be a good idea as well, as we might not know the client's use case (they request rdf/xml on a very large query result, and then the server gets OOM - my case).